# Xdebug and PhpStorm remote does not work

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

Is there a possibility to check if the web server is sending something to Chrome?

I have setting up PhpStorm and the web server in the same way, I have read in 1000 tutorials, but my PhpStorm doesn't receive anything from chrome.

Here are some settings:

php.ini

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so"
xdebug.coverage_enable=on
xdebug.default_enable=on
xdebug.profiler_enable=on
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/tmp"
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_connect_back = on
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
```

I have disabled the firewall on the server. PhpStorm is listening on the port 9001.

Some ideas?

Comment: How do you append an Xdebug cookie in the browser? Do you use Xdebug helper or bookmarks?

Comment: I am using Xdebug helper. I also try with bookmarks. I can't understand if the browser is sending something.

Comment: If you enable the Xdebug helper then it should append it automatically on refresh. Browser does not send anything - that's the connection between Xdebug and PhpStorm. Also, do you really need all these options in php.ini like remote_handler? To work properly, only "zend_extension", "xdebug.remote_enable", "xdebug.remote_host" and "xdebug.remote_port" are required: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Xdebug+Installation+Guide . Note that Apache might use different php.ini file.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is very easy! The only thing I forgot was the ssh tunnel to my remote server from my local machine.

Here an example running config:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

Use as chrome plugin the XDebug Helper
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc

And as last step create an ssh tunnel to the remote server:

```
ssh -R 9001:localhost:9001 user@dev.server.com -N
```